# Swift - Warning: Attempt to present <UITabBarController> on <SignUpViewController> which is already presenting <UIAlertController>

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I want to show the alert than jump to main page, but it didn't jump and show me this warning: 
Attempt to present `<UITabBarController>`  on `<SignUpViewController>` which is already presenting `<UIAlertController>`

here is my code

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Back", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "true", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)

let MyPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController")
presentViewController(MyPage!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I saw some answer let me use viewdidappear or something, but I'm still confusing and don't know how to do that, I have spend several hours not it, please help me fix this problem, Thank you very much!

Comment: when u remove "presentViewController(mypage....)", did alert work?

Comment: @rnsjtngus alert is working, but Mypage didn't show up

Comment: put presentViewController function call in alert completion handler

Comment: the reason why ur code doesn't work is that, at the first presentViewController function called, current view controller is change to alertController. So, second presentViewController function couldn't run

Comment: @rnsjtngus It's work perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put ur presentViewController function in alert completion handler

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "true", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
```

if u put some code in handler, the code executed when u click that "true" button.

For example,

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "true", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: {
    (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    let MyPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController")
    self.presentViewController(MyPage!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```